# Don't know how to reload window and have different output -Modifying DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML document of three pictures like this-

[image]

Now I need to modify the code so that the deleting of images
starts from the beginning, reload the page, and the result like-

[image]

Here is code:

```
export default () => {

    const button = document.querySelector('#b1');
    
    const listener = e => {
        const images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

//        for(let i = 0; i <= images.length; i++) {
        for(let i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const image = images[i];
            if(image.alt) {
                let text = document.createTextNode(image.alt);
                image.parentNode.replaceChild(text, image);
            }
        }
        
        const style = `
            color: yellow; 
            border: 2px solid yellow;
        `;
        
        button.setAttribute('style', style);
        button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        
        button.disabled = true;
        button.textContent = 'Disabled';
    };
    
//    button.onclick = listener;
    button.addEventListener('click', listener);
};
```

Does anybody know what to do?

I tried

```
 for(let i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; **i=i-2**) {
            const image = images[i];
            if(image.alt) {
                let text = document.createTextNode(image.alt);
                image.parentNode.replaceChild(text, image);
            }
        }
```

And I get the desired look(like in the resulting picture), but I need to reload the page and get the output as shown in the resulting picture.

Comment: It seems, if I believe the text on your button, that you want to [replace images with new ones](https://techfunda.com/howto/444/changing-of-images). What, or where, are these new images?

Comment: No, these are the same pictures, look at the picture that I upload. I need to modify DOM on the way to deleting of images starts from the beginning, reload the page, and the result like my last picture